# Display Woocommerce attribute name above product title

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

On the Woocommerce 'shop' page I have the product description below the main image.

Underneath that, I have the range name which I managed to display using the 'WooCommerce Show Attributes' plugin. What I want however is to display the range name above the product title.

Attached is an image of how it looks at the moment.

How can I achieve this?

[image: product]

```
   <figure class="woocom-project">
  <div class="woo-buttons-on-img">

  <a href="#" class="alignnone layzr-bg-transparent"></a>     

 </div>
 <figcaption class="woocom-list-content">

            <h4 class="entry-title">
        <a href="#" title="product description" rel="bookmark">product description</a>
    </h4>
<span class="custom-attributes"><span class="range alma">
<span class="attribute-value">range name,</span></span><br></span>

<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>838.00</span></span>

 abc123

</figcaption>
```

Comment: You can use the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook to add something before or after the product title. [Example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/aff0b5a3cafc12943749b3bc40053155)

Comment: Ok thanks, where does this command go? New to woocommerce and web hooks

Comment: You can place that in your theme functions file (`functions.php`).